# one Post button, each click gives different result (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple comment post for learning purpose (like the pic)

[image]

How do I make the post button post the comment to new input box every time I click. In other words, every time I write a comment in text area and click post button, each of these comments should go to each input box.

ex: I write "i love this" in the text area and click post, that writing is going to display in comment class(0). The next comment "xyz" and click post is going to class(1) etc. So far I only know  how to display to one input box.

Here is my code so far:

```js
function postcomment(){
  var x = document.getElementById("entercomment").innerHTML;
  document.getElementsByClassName("comment")[0].value = x;
}
```

```css
body{
background-color: cyan;
}

#picgoeshere{
  border: 5px solid grey;
  height: 500px;
  width:900px;
   margin: 0 auto; 
}

#picture{
  height: 500px;
  width:900px;
}

#displaycomment{
   border: 3px solid grey; 
   height:250px;
   width:800px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin: top:50%;
} 

.comment{
 height: 41.5px;
 width: 800px;
 border: 0;
}

#typecomment{
   border: 3px solid grey; 
   height:100px;
   width:800px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
#entercomment{
     height:100px;
     width:700px;
}

#submitbutton{
  
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100.9px;
  position: absolute;
  top: ;
  left: 65.7%;
}
```

```html
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="learnjs.css">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="everything">
  <div id="picgoeshere">
  <img src="./images/bisping.jpg" id="picture">
  </div>

   <div id="displaycomment">
     <input type="text" class="comment"></br>
     <input type="text" class="comment"></br> 
     <input type="text" class="comment"></br> 
     <input type="text" class="comment"></br> 
     <input type="text" class="comment"></br> 
     <input type="text" class="comment"></br> 

   </div>

  <div id="typecomment">
   <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="entercomment" placeholder="Enter Your Comment Here"></textarea>
     <button id="submitbutton" onclick="postcomment()"> Post</button>
  </div>

</div>

<script src = "learn.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're using input elements to display the comment?

Comment: no, that what i learned so far. if other elements are better, that's great. but i  do want to only use java script

Comment: @AnuRajan  do you want to display your comment as the format in post box like <pre> tag ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a counter variable and use it to reference each of the comment elements, then add 1 each time the function is called. For example:

```js
var counter = 0;

function postcomment() {

  var x = document.getElementById("entercomment").value;

  document.getElementsByClassName("comment")[counter].value = x;
  
  counter++;

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: cyan;
}
#picgoeshere {
  border: 5px solid grey;
  height: 500px;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#picture {
  height: 500px;
  width: 900px;
}
#displaycomment {
  border: 3px solid grey;
  height: 250px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin: top: 50%;
}
.comment {
  height: 41.5px;
  width: 800px;
  border: 0;
}
#typecomment {
  border: 3px solid grey;
  height: 100px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#entercomment {
  height: 100px;
  width: 700px;
}
#submitbutton {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100.9px;
  position: absolute;
  top: ;
  left: 65.7%;
}
```

```html
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="learnjs.css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="everything">


    <div id="picgoeshere">

      <img src="./images/bisping.jpg" id="picture">
    </div>


    <div id="displaycomment">
      <input type="text" class="comment">
      <br>
      <input type="text" class="comment">
      <br>
      <input type="text" class="comment">
      <br>
      <input type="text" class="comment">
      <br>
      <input type="text" class="comment">
      <br>
      <input type="text" class="comment">
      <br>


    </div>

    <div id="typecomment">

      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="entercomment" placeholder="Enter Your Comment Here"></textarea>

      <button id="submitbutton" onclick="postcomment()">Post</button>

    </div>



  </div>


  <script src="learn.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @AnuRajan no problem :D

Answer (score 1):

This should help you!

```js
function postcomment() {



  var x = document.getElementById("entercomment").value;
  document.getElementById("entercomment").value = ''
  const node = document.createElement("div")
  const deleteButton = document.createElement("span")
  node.innerHTML = x
  node.className = 'cmt'

  deleteButton.className = 'delete-button'
  deleteButton.innerHTML = 'delete'
  deleteButton.onclick = function(e) {
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.target.parentNode)
  }

  node.appendChild(deleteButton)
  const commentContainer = document.getElementById('displaycomment')
  commentContainer.appendChild(node)

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: cyan;
}
#picgoeshere {
  border: 5px solid grey;
  height: 500px;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#picture {
  height: 500px;
  width: 900px;
}
#displaycomment {
  border: 3px solid grey;
  height: 250px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin: top: 50%;
}
.cmt {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
}
.comment {
  height: 41.5px;
  width: 800px;
  border: 0;
}
#typecomment {
  border: 3px solid grey;
  height: 100px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#entercomment {
  height: 100px;
  width: 700px;
}
#submitbutton {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100.9px;
  position: absolute;
  top: ;
  left: 65.7%;
}
.delete-button {
  float: right;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="learnjs.css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="everything">


    <div id="picgoeshere">

      <img src="./images/bisping.jpg" id="picture">
    </div>


    <div id="displaycomment">


    </div>

    <div id="typecomment">

      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="entercomment" placeholder="Enter Your Comment Here"></textarea>

      <button id="submitbutton" onclick="postcomment()">Post</button>

    </div>



  </div>


  <script src="learn.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: wow , thank you. i will start learning this. This is a better way to do what i want . I used input element mainly beacuase it have a delete (x) option. is there a way to delete the posted comment, using ur style?

Comment: @AnuRajan Added the delete ability. Consider approving the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is something you could do.

It is always going to be difficult when you have a fixed number of comments. I did a change in the way you could add elements to the display section once someone add a comment. The way I did, you could add any number of comments.

```js
var commentId = 0;

function postcomment() {

  // Get the comment text
  var commentTextElement = document.querySelector("#entercomment")
  var x = commentTextElement.value;
  //Create a new element to display the comment and add the text content to it, you could use any element here. I just created a div for simple implementation
  var element = document.createElement("div");
  element.setAttribute("id", "comment-id-" + commentId)
  element.innerHTML = x;
  var deleteElement = document.createElement("button");
  deleteElement.innerHTML = "Delete";
  deleteElement.setAttribute("commentId", "comment-id-" + commentId);
  commentId++;
  deleteElement.className = "delete";
  element.appendChild(deleteElement);

  element.className = "posted-comment"
    // Clear the text to enable further comments.
  commentTextElement.value = "";

  // Append the new comment to the display section
  document.querySelector("#displaycomment").appendChild(element);
}

document.querySelector("#displaycomment").addEventListener("click", function(event) {

  if (event.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {

    var buttonElement = event.target;
    var commentId = buttonElement.getAttribute("commentId");
    document.querySelector("#" + commentId).remove();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: cyan;
}
#picgoeshere {
  border: 5px solid grey;
  height: 500px;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#displaycomment {
  border: 3px solid grey;
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin: top: 50%;
}
.comment {
  height: 41.5px;
  width: 800px;
  border: 0;
}
#typecomment {
  border: 3px solid grey;
  height: 100px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#entercomment {
  height: 100px;
  width: 700px;
}
#submitbutton {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100.9px;
  position: absolute;
  top: ;
  left: 65.7%;
}
.posted-comment {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
}
.delete {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="everything">

  <div id="displaycomment">
  </div>

  <div id="typecomment">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="entercomment" placeholder="Enter Your Comment Here"></textarea>
    <button id="submitbutton" onclick="postcomment()">Post</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: . i will start learning this. This is a better way to do what i want . I used input element mainly because it have a delete (x) option. is there a way to delete the posted comment, using ur style?

Comment: Just added the way you could do delete as well.

Answer (score 0):

here's small example of what you want to build

```js
function addNewComment() {
  var comment = document.getElementById('comment').value
  var comments = document.getElementById('comments');
  comments.innerHTML += comment + "<br>";
}
```

```html
<p id=comments></p>
<input type="text" id="comment">
<input type="submit" onclick="addNewComment()" value="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

--Use pre tag to maintain posted comment format
--Auto scroll display comment box to scroll comments.
--use random Id to remove on image click function.

```js
function postcomment() {

  document.getElementById("entercomment").focus();
  var comment = document.getElementById("entercomment").value;
  var randomId = Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 5);
  document.getElementById("displaycomment").innerHTML += "<pre class='preClass' id ='" + randomId + "' />" + comment + "<img src='http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/54/54528.svg' onclick='removeComment(this.id);' id='" + randomId + "' class='preimg' /> </pre> ";
  document.getElementById("entercomment").value = "";

}

function removeComment(element) {
  var ele = document.getElementById(element);
  ele.parentElement.removeChild(ele);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: cyan;
}
#picgoeshere {
  border: 5px solid grey;
  height: 500px;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#picture {
  height: 500px;
  width: 900px;
}
#displaycomment {
  border: 3px solid grey;
  height: 250px;
  max-width: 800px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin: top: 50%;
}
.comment {
  height: 41.5px;
  width: 800px;
  border: 0;
}
#typecomment {
  border: 3px solid grey;
  height: 100px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#entercomment {
  height: 100px;
  width: 700px;
}
#submitbutton {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100.9px;
  position: absolute;
  top: ;
  left: 65.7%;
}
.preClass {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted blue;
  position: relative;
}
.preimg {
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="everything">


  <div id="picgoeshere">

    <img src="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/43/53/Tx8wbO.jpg" id="picture">
  </div>


  <div id="displaycomment">
    <!--  <div id="comment"> </div>-->

  </div>

  <div id="typecomment">

    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="entercomment" placeholder="Enter Your Comment Here"></textarea>

    <button id="submitbutton" onclick="postcomment()">Post</button>

  </div>
```